# react-native-maps, rendering dynamic markers post run-time

Tags: marker, react-native-maps

Delete this question please, someone has helped me on another thread.

I am trying to generate markers at certain times in my app so that it will show a blank map at launch, but then sometime later, markers can show up and disappear at certain times.

My state variables are set up like this:

```
class Map extends Component {   

state = {
    markers: [{
        key: null,
        contactName: null,
        location: null,
    }]
}
```

The code I am trying to generate the markers with is as follows:

```
renderMarker = ({ key, contactName, location }) => {
        console.log('renderMarker: ' + key + ', ' + contactName + ', ' + location);
        return this.state.markers.map(Marker => (
            <MapView.Marker  
                key = { key }
                coordinate = {{ 
                    latitude: location[0],
                    longitude: location[1]
                }}
                //image = { carIcon }
                title = { contactName } />
        ))
}
```

The console.log in there is generating the correct data, so it is returning for example:

```
renderMarker: 389djhJHDjdkh392sdk, Steve, -30.498767387,120.4398732
```

My render function looks like this:

```
render() {
    return (
    <MapContainer>
        <MapView 
            style = { styles.map }
            region = { this.state.mapRegion }
            showsUserLocation = { true }
            followUserLocation = { true }
            onRegionChangeComplete = { this.onRegionChangeComplete.bind(this) }>
        </MapView>    
    </MapContainer>
    )
}
```

But nothing shows up on the map.    I have been scouring the interwebs but I can't find a followable example.   Do I need to add something to my render() function to make this work?  My thoughts were I won't need to because renderMarker is doing that work.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Your render function is not rendering the markers as such? You should have `{this.renderMarkers()}` inside the render method I believe. See this example https://github.com/RioBus/react-native-app/blob/d05ab66d5c73af7b0ecd508c9168bc7391bf405c/src/pages/Map.js